# Autoencoder Training vs Validation

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

estaba entrenando una red autoencoder que tiene las siguientes variables: ['fecha', 'latitud', 'longitud', 'altitud', 'velocidad', 'cog', 'nsat','ignicion'] , la fecha tiene año/mes/dia hora/min/seg.
Primero partí entrenando la red separando la fecha en 6 columnas, el cual me salio el siguiente resultado y su arquitectura:

Train on 4007935 samples, validate on 1494893 samples

**Configuración**

**Función de activación**      Tanh

**Función perdida Mean**       squared error(mse)

**Algoritmos optimiza-dores**  Adam

**Numero de épocas**           50

**Numero de lotes(batch size)** 400

**Métrica**                    R-squared

**Regularizador l2(1e-8)**     Hidden layer 1 y 6

**Tiempo de entrenamiento**     6032

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La red tienen un buen rendimiento, pero decide usar epoch unix time(calcula segundos de 1970) en vez de la fecha que ocupa 6 columnas lo cual reduciría el numero de columnas.Y lo entrene con la misma arquitectura y salio el siguiente resultado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Uno diría que tiene un buen rendimiento pero es raro que training loss sea mayor que el validation loss,luego probé con otra arquitectura pensando que era un error pero sigue teniendo este comportamiento. 
Nunca me ha sucedido esto y tampoco se el motivo porque sucede. Tienen alguna explicación de lo que esta sucediendo.
Después cambie la siguiente configuración, cambie el shuffle a False y vi que ya no tenia ese comportamiento, si no como de la primera imagen(no tengo entrenado le modelo todavia) que estaría bien.

```
autoencoder = model.fit(X_train,X_train,
      batch_size=batch_size,
      epochs=nb_epoch,
      **shuffle** = False,
      validation_data=(X_test,X_test))
```

¿Porque sucede esto ? ¿debería dejar en fecha completa o en unix? ¿A alguien le sucedió esto?

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Los mecanismos de regularización L1/L2 o Dropout son desactivados en el momento de validación esta puede ser la explicación de la diferencia en los resultados. Al parecer es un error común, puedes revisar [aquí](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/187335/validation-error-less-than-training-error).

Yo te recomendaría hacer cross validation para evaluar el modelo y dividir la fecha en dos columnas año/mes/dia y hora/min/seg, no creo que sea necesario dividirla en 6 columnas para este caso.